# Using c++ sockets - Having aggravating errors using accept() and file descriptors

Tags: c++, sockets, client-server

I've been using the site for a while and (after this semester) look forward to contributing back!  However, I would like your help one last time and no other answers seem to have turned up any help.

BACKGROUND : Designing a basic chat room using c++, sockets, and a client/server architecture with up to ten clients talking to the server.  Anything one client says is echoed among all clients and the server (with the exception of the sending client).

PROBLEM : The error occurs at the recv call as the while loop condition in the clientTalk function.  I get a "Receive failed : Bad file descriptor" but neither the server nor the client "crash" completely and no noticeable change in behavior occurs, despite the fact that the receive bombed completely.

ATTEMPTS TO SOLVE:

- Google and SOf. For 2 hours...
- Moving variables, playing around with socket settings and opening/closing

-Valgrind:

```
==773== Warning: invalid file descriptor 96600128 in syscall read()

Recieve failed: Bad file descriptor
==773== Thread 2:
==773== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==773==    at 0x4015A0: ??? (in /nethome/users/ghm455/CS284/ChatServer/server)
==773==    by 0x4E39E99: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==773==    by 0x5442CBC: clone (clone.S:112)
==773==
==773== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==773==    at 0x401614: ??? (in /nethome/users/ghm455/CS284/ChatServer/server)
==773==    by 0x4E39E99: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==773==    by 0x5442CBC: clone (clone.S:112)
==773==
==773== Warning: invalid file descriptor 96600128 in syscall close()
```

The first warning occurs at my accept statement.  The receive failed occurs at the recv and the last warning occurs on attempted close.  This was determined by cout statements littered throughout the code.

CODE: Below. I'll post the client if you believe the error lies there, but everything points to this being a server side problem.

```
`#define SERVER_PORT 9999        /* define a server port number */

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

//Globals - descriptorArray holds client FDs.  arraySize is its size.
//soc holds the information on the server's socket.
//m is the global mutex shared among the server and all clients
const int MAX_CLIENT = 10;
int descriptorArray[MAX_CLIENT];
int arraySize = 0;
int soc;
pthread_mutex_t m;

struct thread_info
{
pthread_t threadID; //Stores the ID number returned by pthread_create
int threadNumber;   //We have to number incoming threads correctly
char *messageSent;  //Message taken in from command line
};

int main()
{
void exitHandler(int sig); // Function that handles the control-C
void* clientTalk(void *arg); // Reads and writes with clients
struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
int option = 1;
unsigned int clientCount;
uint8_t *new_socket;

//Initialize the socket
soc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (soc < 0)
{
    cout << "ERROR : problem opening socket" <<endl;
    return 1;
}

//Create socket structure
bzero((char *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

//Binding host address
if (bind(soc, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
{
    cout << "ERROR : problem occured while binding" <<endl;
    close(soc);
    exit(1);
}
if(setsockopt(soc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*) &option, sizeof(option)) < 0)
{
    printf("setsockopt failed\n");
    close(soc);
    exit(1);
} 

signal(SIGINT, exitHandler);
listen(soc, MAX_CLIENT);

clientCount = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
int clientID;
//cout << "Z " <<endl;
while(clientID = accept(soc, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, (socklen_t*)&clientCount))
{
    //printf( "A");
    if (clientID < 0 )  
    {   
        perror("ERROR ON ACCEPT");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        pthread_t newClient;
        new_socket = (uint8_t*)malloc(1);
        *new_socket = clientID;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
        if (arraySize < 10)
        {
            descriptorArray[arraySize++] = newClient;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "There are already 10 clients connected!" << endl;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
        if( pthread_create(&newClient, NULL, clientTalk, &new_socket) < 0)
        {
            perror("ERROR Creating thread");
            return 1;
        }
        cout << "Assigned!" <<endl;
        pthread_join(newClient, NULL);
    }
}
close(soc);
return 0;
}

void exitHandler(int sig)
{
sig = sig + 0; //Removing the warning. A clean compile looks a lot nicer.
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    write(descriptorArray[i], "WARNING: Server exiting in ten seconds. End your conversation!", 1000);
}
cout << "WARNING: Server exiting in ten seconds.  ";
cout << "End your conversation!" << endl;
sleep(10f); 
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    close(descriptorArray[i]);
}
close(soc);
exit(1);
}


void* clientTalk(void* arg)
{
int* myFD = (int*) arg;
char buffer[2000];
read(*myFD, buffer, 20);
char username[20];
//strcpy(username, buffer); // Takes in the username and stores it
char movableString[2000];
int amount_read;

// for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
// {
    //strcpy(movableString, username);
//  strcat(movableString, " has joined the room!");
    //if (descriptorArray[0] != *myFD)
    //{
    //  write(descriptorArray[0], movableString, 2000);
    //}
//}
cout << "x" << endl;
int arrayLocation;  
while ( (amount_read = recv(*myFD, buffer, 2000, MSG_WAITALL)) > 0)
{
    cout << " Um" << endl;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        if (descriptorArray[i] == *myFD)
        {
            arrayLocation = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    strcpy(movableString, username);
    strcat(movableString, ": ");
    strcat(movableString, buffer);
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        //if (i != arrayLocation)
        //{
            write(*myFD, movableString, 2000); 
        //}
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
}
if (amount_read == 0)
{
    cout << username << "disconnected unexpectedly" <<endl;
    fflush(stdout);
}
if (amount_read == -1)
{
    perror("Recieve failed");
}


pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    if (descriptorArray[i] == *myFD)
    {
        arrayLocation = i;
        break;
    }
}

for (int i = arrayLocation; i < arraySize - 1; i++)
{
    descriptorArray[i] = descriptorArray[i + 1];
}
arraySize--;

pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
close(*myFD);
pthread_exit(NULL);
free(arg);
}
```

`

I'll be monitoring this site to answer any questions you may have.  I apologize in advance for making any novice mistakes in asking a question.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: When you pass your socket to your thread you use an `int8_t`, that should be `size_t` (the size of a pointer) and in C++ you should use `new` rather than `malloc`.

Comment: Should be int as the posix definition of accept returns an int

Comment: Sorry but I stopped reading at `no noticeable change in behavior occurs, despite the fact that the receive bombed completely` which made no sense to me at all

Comment: And, FYI, 2 hours is not a long time to be trying to solve a programming problem!

Answer (score 1):

The error means the file descriptor passed to the read function is not a valid file descriptor, so the first thing to do when debugging is to make sure the value of the file descriptor in the ClientTalk function is the same as in main.

@J.N. is right in the comments. They will not be the same because the FD is an int and you are only passing the first byte to the function (and converting it to an int* pointer.)

You might want to write this program in C as it doesn't look like C++ code.

1. Change ClientID and new_socket to int / int*. 
   Use consistent types, and use the types in the function definition accept returns an int so use int  / int* for everything.
2. When calling malloc use sizeof not the number of bytes whenever possible.

There might be other problems.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two issues here. First, you never call `pthread_mutex_init` so your mutex was never created to a sane state (although it will be zeroed if it's at global scope).

Secondly, you pass `&new_socket` as the `void*` to your thread. This is of type `uint8_t**` while inside your `clientTalk` function you C-style-cast cast it to `int*` which is a totally different pointer type and will certainly not provide the result you desire.